# Get webcam device access notification

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, directshow

I want to get notified whenever a process tries to access webcam along with information about the process.

So far I have identified physical device name of the webcam using `SetupDiGetClassDevs` and `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME)` which looks something like `\Device\0000003c`.

I can also see that processes like skype have an open handle to the above device. Is there a way to monitor such open handle requests(in driver mode or user mode)?I can query all processes and their open handles using `NtQuerySystemInformation()` and `NtQueryObject()`.Is there a better way?

Also i have looked into `IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification()`.For this i guess i would be needing a pnp driver.

Is there some other mechanism which i can use to achieve this?I looked into directshow but i am not sure if the above can be achieved using `directshow`

Comment: only way - create filter driver, which attached to device and report create requests

Comment: thanks..that would be a pnp driver or a minifilter driver can monitor such requests?

Comment: no, this must be  wdm driver. you can register it as upper filter for device or in runtime monitor interface arrival via  `IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification` and attach. this can not be minifilter (it attach only for filesystem devices)

Comment: also you need filter not all file open requests on device, but only for files, which name begin from `KSSTRING_Pin` (look in *ks.h*) - `"{146F1A80-4791-11D0-A5D6-28DB04C10000}"`

Comment: Thanks again..So i guess looking into toastmon sample of windows sdk would help.Am i in the right direction?